# PHP Class auto-adjusting functions?

Tags: php

I'm writing a class that I'd like to be able to expand pretty easily, but each variable needs either 3 or 4 functions to go with it.  I'm trying to think up a way I can utilize arrays or some other data type so that I can write the mandatory functions and use them with each variable without having to write more and more code, just simply add a new variable to the array and it's handled automatically.  Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data handling you are trying to achieve? What you're referring to is doable, but I need more details to help you.

Comment: It was more of an experimental question, where the data wasn't all that important.  I just wanted to know how other people would go about solving this. I had wanted to make a singleton and have it expand automatically with some database interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). You can use `__get` to get a value from your data storage (for example array) when an inaccessible property is called, and `__set` when it's set. The `__call` method is called when an inaccessible method is called, so you can check for either one of you 4 needed methods there. Please note that magic methods are a bit slower than manually coding all methods.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in implementing `__call` in your class, as a catch-all method. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for more info. In this way your object will be able to receive method calls for methods that don't actually exist, but are dynamically dispatched based on their name. You would check if this method being requested corresponds to one of these expansions that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
function myfunc($requiredParameter, $arrayWithOptionalParameters=array()) {
    if(!empty($arrayWithOptionalParameters['somekey'])) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```